# Does nodejs supports updating many collection in one router?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I tried updating my two collections in one router but it keeps on giving me error:

> `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:494:11)
>       at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:501:3)`

Here is what I did:

**api.js**

```
router.put('/editbloodrequest', function(req, res) {

    //this works
    Bloodrequest.findOne({ _id:"5c1d2c8c68503b0adceffa92"}, function(err, bloodrequest) {
        if (err) throw err;                    
        bloodrequest.request_status = "claimed"; 
    });

    //but after inserting this, it gives me error
    Blooddonation.findOne({ _id:"5c00fa03dadb0c3b00739dd9"}, function(err, blooddonation) {
        if (err) throw err; 
        blooddonation.blood_group = "test"; 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I strongly suggest that you abandon callbacks and use Mongo's *Promise* behavior instead. Unless you intended to by executing both requests concurrently, this would be the way you would express this using promises:

```
Bloodrequest.findOne({ _id:"..." }).then(bloodrequest => {
    bloodrequest.request_status = "claimed";
})
.then(() => Blooddonation.findOne({ _id:"..." }).then(blooddonation => {
    blooddonation.blood_group = "test";
});
```

Second, I'm guessing you cut some code from your example; nowhere in there do you actually respond (using `res`). Based on the error, I'm guessing you attempted to set `res` in *both* of your callbacks. You can only respond once, that error typically means you already redirected / responded / etc. and now are attempting to do it again.

Usually you'll do this:

```
Bloodrequest.findOne({ _id:"..." }).then(bloodrequest => {
    bloodrequest.request_status = "claimed";
})
.then(() => Blooddonation.findOne({ _id:"..." }).then(blooddonation => {
    blooddonation.blood_group = "test";
}).then(() => {
    // set your positive res response
}).catch(error => {
    // set your error res response
    // since you're using promises, if any of the above steps fail, you'll
    // end up here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need require model of collections which you want to update in api.js

In route handler function, you need a transaction among related collection. You can you **fawn npm** to make this easier
https://www.npmjs.com/package/fawn